# Exiting a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, line-breaks

I know I'm missing something really simple here....but I cannot put my finger on it.

My code is trying to find divisors for the items in "numbers". When count reaches 10 I know I have found the first item in numbers which has 10 divisors...but I cannot see to exit the loop. It just keeps printing the items in numbers that have 10 or more divisors.

I thought it was the indent, but no. I then moved the counter inside the first for loop to see if that was it, and still nothing.

```
numbers = []

numbers = [i for i in range(1, 100)]

for i in range(1, 100):
    test = sum(numbers[0:i])
    count = 0   

    for j in range(1, test+1):

        if test % j == 0:
            count +=1

        if count == 10:
            print test
            break
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Is the code correct? It seems `for j` should be intended at the same level as `count = 0` above it. In that case you have two nested loops and `break` breaks only the inner-most.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted it wrong. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

`break` breaks only the inner-most `for` loop. You need to check for `count == 10` after that as well:

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    test = sum(numbers[0:i])
    count = 0   

    for j in range(1, test+1):

        if test % j == 0:
            count +=1

        if count == 10:
            print test
            break # Breaks for j but not for i

    if count == 10:
        break # Breaks for i
```

Comment: Thanks :) Looks like I'm going to have to work on understanding how breaks work. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to exit both `for` loops. There are two options:

1) Put the code in a function and use `return` instead of `break`

```
def process_something():
    for a in items:
        for b in other_items:
            if some_condition:
                return
```

2) Use a helper variable to detect that the outer loop should break too:

```
for a in items:
    done = False
    for b in other_items:
        if some_condition:
            done = True
            break
    if done:
        break
```

In your case, you can use `if count == 10:` instead of `if done:` but I don't like duplicating "application logic" ([DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), so `count == 10` should be in code only once. But this is a matter of taste.

3) Wrap the outer loop in a `try:`/`catch ...:` and raise exception instead of `break`, but please don't do this.

Comment: Why should 3) be avoided?

Comment: @user5061 It's abuse of exception mechanism for something that isn't actually an exception - isn't an error. Well, generators use this trick too - they raise `StopIteration` after all items were yielded, this is explained in PEP 234. Other, more practical problem is that you should catch only exactly the "breaking" exception and nothing else - in case a "real" exception is raised inside the loops, so it is not discarded silently. Therefore you should define new exception type just for this (similarly how `StopIteration` is raised only for "end" of a generator).